# synchronizing files and symlinks between two linux os

Tags: linux, synchronization

I am facing with the bug following:
https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4531

rsync will always get the older symlink of the other side overwrite
the newer one on the local side.

Wayne has suggested to use unison, however it is a non-developing old
project that I have suspect to use.

What can you suggest me for ?

My main aim is to syncronize file, directories, links for 2 nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unison is ok, as long as your file/folders name don't use unicode, especially cross platform.  Can't hurt to give it a try.

---

See [Here](http://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/wiki/index.php?n=Main.UnisonFAQCharacterEncoding) for the limitation on unicode in filename.

Comment: I clarify my answer a bit... problem is with non-ascii filename/folder name.  The content is treated as binary.

Comment: I used the following for synching and works good. unison -ui text /opt/folder1/ ssh://machine2//opt/folder1  -group -owner  -times -batch -prefer newer